Websocket connecting only after the ayncio finish the background task
I have a process route in my fast api server :-
@router.post("/process")
async def handle_options(data: Dict[str, Any]):
  #.... other code
  asyncio.create_task(editing(videoId, values, videoWidth, videoHeight, fps, userData))
  return {'The editing started'}

async def editing(videoId, values, videoWidth, videoHeight, fps, userData):
   recordingFile = os.path.join(temp_dir, f"recording_{videoId}.mp4")
   webFile = os.path.join(temp_dir, f"final_edited_{videoId}.mp4")
   ffmpeg_change_bitrate = [ 'ffmpeg', '-i', recordingFile , '-b:v', '5M', f'{webFile}' ]

   subprocess.run(ffmpeg_change_bitrate)
   print('Completed Editing, it took 4 minutes')

The route creates a task that would run in the background and without waiting for the entire editing to complete it just return the response back to the user. This works fine, it did creates the task and immediately return the response ( NOTE :- The editing take few minutes before complete)
Now I also have a websocket route :-
@router.websocket("/logs")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, videoId: str = Query(...)):
    await manager.connect(websocket)
    
    # Print connection details
    print(f"Client connected: {websocket.client.host} at {datetime.now()}")

After the user receives the response from the server from the first request, it redirects user to a loading page where I connected them with the /logs websocket connection, it would be used to keep the process of video editing updated, but instead of connecting this immediately when the user requests, it connects itself only when the asyncio.create_task(editing(videoId, values, videoWidth, videoHeight, fps, userData)) asyncio task completes.
The asyncio.create_task editing function blocks every other route, function to work until it finishes

create_task does not magically make your code run in parallel, it "just" inserts another task to be run on the current event loop. Your subprocess.run call then locks the event loop, since it's not async compatible (the other statements do as well, but they don't take any real time). "The task is executed in the loop returned by get_running_loop()". Use a thread (or better, use a separate worker process that does the actual heavy lifting, and poll that / check redis for progress / similar.

@MatsLindh Can you please show the example using threads

Does this answer your question? I would also strongly recommend having a look at this answer. Finally, as it has already been suggested to a previous question of yours, see this answer as well.

@Chris Can you please show an example / answer with my code I shared in the question

Your editing(...) function is entirely synchronous, as it has no await statements in it. This means that once the task is scheduled, no other async code will run until it has finished.
There is an async version of create_subprocess, which you can use as follows:
import asyncio

async def editing(videoId, values, videoWidth, videoHeight, fps, userData):
   recordingFile = os.path.join(temp_dir, f"recording_{videoId}.mp4")
   webFile = os.path.join(temp_dir, f"final_edited_{videoId}.mp4")
   ffmpeg_change_bitrate = ['-i', recordingFile , '-b:v', '5M', f'{webFile}' ]

   await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec('ffmpeg', ffmpeg_change_bitrate)
   print('Completed Editing, it took 4 minutes')


I tried the code, but I am getting NotImplementedError with it
